# C++ how to make a prototype of this kind of constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am honestly not sure how to google this even, and as my attempts have failed to do so, can you tell me how to write a prototype of constructor so that I can use it this way?

```
// MyClass.h
class Object;
class MyClass {
    Object a;
    Object b;
    std::string c;

    public:
    MyClass(int, int, std::string&); // I do not know how to declare this properly
};
// so that I can write this:
MyClass::MyClass(int a, int b, std::string& c = "uninstantialised") : a(a), b(b) {
    this->c = c;
}
// so that when I call the constructor like this:
Object a();
Object b();
MyClass mc(a, b);
// it doesn't produce an error when std::string argument is not specified.
```

Thanks!

Comment: The parameter default should go to the function declaration and omitted from the definiiton.

Comment: Your default argument should be in the prototype not in the initialization. And most likely, you also want a const reference, as a temporary shouldn't bind with a mutable reference. (Except if you use MSVC, who is wrong about that)

Comment: `Object a();` -- This does not call the constructor.  This declares a function called `a` that takes no parameters and returns an `Object`.

Comment: I needed to declare an Object a and b as those are the parameters that MyClass constructor uses. :)

Comment: @Amaterastis: Sure, but the code you wrote doesn't do that. It declares functions named `a` and `b` that would return an `Object` if they were called.

Comment: I really like the word `uninstantialised`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default arguments need to be specified in the declaration, not in the implementation. Furthermore, you should take the string by value, not by reference, and move it into the `MyClass::c` member:

```
public:
    MyClass(int a, int b, std::string c = "uninstantialised");

// ...

MyClass::MyClass(int a, int b, std::string c)
    : a(a), b(b), c(std::move(c))
{ }
```

Taking by value and using `std::move()` is not required, but recommended as it can be more efficient since it avoids copying the string in some cases.

I recommend renaming private data members to something that avoids the same name being used for something else. Here, `c` is both the private member as well as the constructor parameter. You should use something different for the members. Like `a_`, `b_` and `c_` for example. Appending an underscore is a popular way to name private data members.

Comment: Thanks! :) I didn't know how to solve this, you saved me. :) Why would you use different names if you can access all members using this keyword?

Comment: @Amaterastis Because when you don't use the `this` keyword, people reading the code might get confused whether you simply forgot to use the `this` keyword or you didn't use it on purpose. It makes code harder to read. Also, whenever someone sees `c_` in code, it's immediately obvious that this is a private data member. No need to go figure out what it is.

Comment: I can agree with that logic, although I am always using this-> to notate if it is private member or the argument.

Comment: @Amaterastis That's up to you. I did too some years ago, then I got tired of all my code starting with `this->` everywhere. It just looks bad and is harder to read. I only use `this->` when it's actually required now.

Comment: It's probably too late to change it now, but I'll try to fix that in some other project. :) Thanks for noting this to me! :)